# Recommended column type for an ID that is 16 digits long (& no minus values)

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have an ID in a MySQL database that has will need to store an ID value that will be upto 16 digits long & will never contain negative values.

What is the most optimum column type for this? I was thinking bigint(11) - or would something else be better?

Comment: Yes, `unsigned bigint` or just `bigint`

Comment: you recommend bigint(11)? Thats what i was going for

Comment: `11` is just for leading zeros and since you have up to `16` digits it does not make sense to use `11`. It does not affect the size of the data type

Comment: What is the id being used for?  How is it generated?

Comment: If your ID has leading zeros, you'll have to use a char(16).  I usually only use int fields for numbers.  I'd probably put the ID in a char(16) field.

Comment: Jurgen - if you add this as an answer i'll accept it for you